# Why isn't root.quit() or root.destroy() working but only the combination of both?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program I implemented a Popup with some entries for user input. That Popup has an 'Enter' button to confirm and collect the input and then close the Popup automatically.
For closing the Popup I found the `root.destroy()` and `root.quit()` methods (in my code self.master instead of root). I thought I kind of understand how to use them but apparently I didn't. :/

```py
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        #some irrelevant widgets

        btn_new_element = tk.Button(self, text='new', command=self.new_element)
        btn_new_element.pack()


    def new_element(self):

        root = tk.Toplevel()
        popup = Pupup(root, someData, otherData)
        root.mainloop()

        #do some other stuff



class Popup(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, var1, var2):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        #some widgets

        btn = tk.Button(self, text='Enter', command=lambda a=var1, b=var2: self.foo(a, b))
        btn.pack()


    def foo(self, a, b):

        #do something with widget data

        self.master.quit()
        self.master.destroy()
```

In `foo()` first I only used `destroy()`. It closes the Popup but the program didnt continue with the code in `new_element()`. (It seemed as if the `mainloop()` was still looping.)
Using `quit()` produced the opposite result: the rest of the code in `new_element()` was executed but the Popup was still there.
Only using `quit()` and `destroy()` in that particular order gave me the result I wanted.

According to thousands of examples on the internet it should be possible using only one of the two methods. Why isn't it working in my code?

EDIT: deleted var1 and var2 from the MainWindow constructor (copy and paste mistake during creation of this question.

EDIT: Also I get the feeling the the problem might be the scope of the root varibale. In `new_element()` do I create a local variable called root or do I overwrite the global root variable?

Comment: This code won't work as-is because you're trying to create an instance of `MainWindow` before you've defined the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you're calling `mainloop` more than once. You should not do that. It causes problems very much like the one that you're having.

If your goal is to create a popup window, and then wait for the user to dismiss the popup window, tkinter has a method specifically for that. It's called `wait_window`, and it won't return until the window it is waiting on has been destroyed.

```
top = tk.Toplevel()
popup = Popup(top, "some data", "other data")
top.wait_window(top)
```

You can put additional code after `top.wait_window(top)`, and it won't execute until the popup has been destroyed.

Within your popup code, your button simply needs to call `destroy` on the popup window. You shouldn't call `quit`.

```
def foo(self, a, b):

    #do something with widget data

    self.master.destroy()
```

Comment: This seems like the solution you need @Maxxx

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your example (copy paste not working), but after arranging things to work (giving values and stuff), here is your problem:

```py
    def new_element(self):
        root = tk.Toplevel()
        popup = Pupup(root, someData, otherData)
        # root.mainloop() # < ------ This generates a new main loop, with is destroyed.
```

here is a complete code that works:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Popup(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, var1, var2):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        #some widgets

        btn = tk.Button(self, text='Enter', command=lambda a=var1, b=var2: self.foo(a, b))
        btn.pack()


    def foo(self, a, b):

        #do something with widget data

        self.master.quit()
        # self.master.destroy()


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, var1, var2):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        #some irrelevant widgets

        btn_new_element = tk.Button(self, text='new', command=self.new_element)
        btn_new_element.pack()


    def new_element(self):

        root = tk.Toplevel()
        popup = Popup(root, 'a', 'b')
        # root.mainloop()

        #do some other stuff

root = tk.Tk()
window = MainWindow(root,1,2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if you added some explanation outside of the code. Without an explanation, we must compare your code line-by-line and character-by-character with the original to see what has changed, and then try to figure out which changes were necessary to solve the problem and which were just personal preferences.

Comment: Look at the EDIT, I guess this is why you couldn't run the code. But still this is not the solution of my problem because with your code quit() not only closes the Popup but the MainWindow as well.

Comment: I believe that the answer is to remove the second loop, `root.mainloop()`, that you create and to then use `root.destroy()` to close the `Toplevel` window you created.

Comment: @MatthewGadsden this creates again the problem that the #doSomeOtherStuff-code in `new_element()` isn't executed until I click the 'new'-button in the MainWindow again.

Comment: @Maxxx I see yes. For `#doSomeOtherStuff` in `new_element()` do you need data from the new window created for the code to run?`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you have created a second loop, to fix this you can just remove the second loop, and then the `.destroy()` function should work just fine.

Like this

```py
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__():
        # your init code

    def new_element(self):
        root = tk.Toplevel()
        popup = Popup(root, 1, 0)

class Popup(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, var1, var2):
        # your init code

    def foo(self, a, b):
        self.master.destroy()
```

Another comment I will make is that I believe the way you have structured this windows is misleading, and could cause confusion (keep in mind this is just preference and is no longer about "real" problems).

I believe instead of having a `Popup(Frame)` class, you should create a `Popup(Toplevel)` class.

Like this

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        btn_new_element = tk.Button(self, text='new', command=self.new_element)
        btn_new_element.pack()
        self.master = master
        self.pack()

    def new_element(self):
        popup = Popup(self.master, 1, 0)


class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, var1, var2):
        super().__init__(master)
        #some widgets
        btn = tk.Button(self, text='Enter', command=lambda a=var1, b=var2: self.foo(a,b))
        btn.pack()

    def foo(self, a, b):
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

When you create a Toplevel element it needs a master, the master will be the main window in this instance. When you use self.destroy within the Toplevel class, you are not destroying the Toplevels master, but instead you are destroying the Toplevel itself.

Comment: Changing `Popup(tk.Frame)` to `Popup(tk.Toplevel)` somehow creates a empty Popup in addition to the one is supposed to pop up.
However @BryanOakley 's solution works fine.

Comment: This would be because you didn't remove the line `root = tk.Toplevel()` from `new_element()` which would mean you would create two `Toplevel` elements, `root = tk.Toplevel()` and the `Popup(tk.Toplevel)`

Comment: This way the MainWindow and the Popup share the same master, so both windows are destroyed.

Comment: This is not how a Toplevel() element works, the top levels master is the main window, but you destroy the toplevel with self.destroy(), you don’t destroy the toplevel’s master. The code I provided should work find if you just copy and paste it into a blank document.